# Question on installation of android-x86-8.1-r2.x86_64.rpm on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: installation, linux

I installed the android-x86-8.1-r2.x86_64.rpm package on Ubuntu 18.04 using the following commands as suggested by [Release Note 8.1-r2](https://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-8-1-r2.html) but it didn't add boot entries to the grub2 menu.

- sudo apt install alien
- sudo alien -ci android-x86-8.1-r2.x86_64.rpm

---

> **Question**: What are the definitions of the boot entries I need to add to the 40_custom grub file in order to add android-x86-8.1-r2 to my grub2 boot menu?

---

Based on the answer below I tried adding the following menu entry to the 40_custom grub file. I also tried changing system.img to system.sfs.

---

menuentry "Android-x86 8.1-r2" --class android-x86 {
        insmod part_gpt
        search --file --no-floppy --set=root /android-8.1-r2/system.img
        linux /android-8.1-r2/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=remix_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive CMDLINE
        initrd /android-8.1-r2/initrd.img
}

---

Based on [How to Install Android in Dual Boot with Linux](https://linuxhint.com/install_android_dual_boot_linux/) I also tried adding the following menu entry to the 40_custom grub file.

---

menuentry "Android-x86 8.1-r2" {
search --set=root --file /android-8.1-r2/kernel
linux /android-8.1-r2/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive
initrd /android-8.1-r2/initrd.img
}

---

Neither of the two menu entries above work. When I update grub it produces the following output which seems to indicate grub isn't recognizing the menu entry, and my computer continues to boot directly into Ubuntu 18.04.

---

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done

---

My computer hard drive has a single Linux ext4 partition, and the contents of /android-8.1-r2 are as follows:

---

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Jul 21 09:40 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1358699 Jun 13 02:11 initrd.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7437056 Jun 13 02:11 kernel
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1424814 Jun 13 02:11 ramdisk.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 877621248 Jun 13 02:11 system.sfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that grub was actually configured with an option to boot Android, but I wasn't seeing this option because grub was configured to automatically boot Ubuntu. I added the # to the beginning of the following lines in /etc/default/grub, ran "sudo update-grub", and now my computer gives me the option to boot Android.

#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
#GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

I also determined the menu entry I added to 40_custom wasn't necessary as it resulted in a redundant option to boot Android in the grub boot menu, so I deleted this menu entry (which I had manually added as described in my question above) from my 40_custom file.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you must edit 40_custom and write this into the file:

```
menuentry 'android' --class android-x86 {
        insmod part_gpt
        search --file --no-floppy --set=root /android-8.1-r2./system.sfs
        linux /android-8.1-r2./kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=remix_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive CMDLINE
        initrd /android-8.1-r2./initrd.img
}
```

and then update your grub. Maybe you must change paths.

Comment: My folder name is android-8.1-r2. There is no system.img file in this folder, but there is a system.sfs file along with kernel, initrd.img and ramdisk.img files and a data folder.

Comment: ok then change it from system.img to system.sfs

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work as I indicated in my updated question above.

Comment: Did you get any error if you start Android?

Comment: My problem is I can't start Android. I don't get an option to boot it when I start my computer since update-grub doesn't seem to be recognizing it when I add it to the 40_custom file.

Comment: Did you tried 'sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom' and then grub-update?

Comment: The 40_custom file was already executable. I resolved my problem as described in the answer I posted.